# iOS UIScrollView can't scroll when I click textfield twice at keyboard shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a problem about the iOS at UIScrollview in Objective-C.

I drag the UI auto layout about below photo.

[image]

When I click the textfield, the keyboard will show, and I need can scroll the view.

[image]

It is seem is ok, but when I click done button and hide the keyboard,

I click textfield again, the keyboard will show, but I can't scroll the view again.

And other problem is like upper photo,

When I scrolled on the tableview , the tableview is can't scroll,

it is scroll the outside scroll view, how can I set the touch on the tableview , it's scroll tableview .

My keyboard event code below and I had upload this page complete code and auto layout project in GitHub:
[this problem link](https://github.com/dickfala/scrollProblem.git)

Have anyone can give me some help? thank you very much.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

      [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
     self.tf.inputAccessoryView = self.keyboardToolbarVw;

 }

 - (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
 {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
 }

 - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
 {
     NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
     CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
     UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
     self.sv.contentInset = contentInsets;
     self.sv.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

     CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
     aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
     if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.view.frame.origin) ) {
         CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.view.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
         [self.sv setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
     }
 }


 - (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
 {
     UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
     self.sv.contentInset = contentInsets;
     self.sv.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
 }

 - (IBAction)keyboardToolbarDoenBtnAction:(UIButton *)sender {
     [self.tf resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Comment: You have a wonderful debugger. Debug! Put breakpoints on your `keyboardWasShown` and `keyboardWillBeHidden` and look to see when they are called. Are they being called only when you expect they will be? Also look at the value you are assigning to your scroll view's `contentInset` each time you change it. Does it make sense every time?

Comment: I got NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
  the kbSize.height is zero twice. why?@@

Comment: I replaced UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey to UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey. It is can get value twice. The first problem is solved. But second is how can touch the tableview can scroll? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing you code, it seems problem `UIScrollView` frames update in `- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification`

Instead of doing such manually work on frames, please try **[IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)**

I’ll suggest to use **IQKeyboardManager** library in all our projects :) It’s a drop-in universal library which allows you to prevent issues of the keyboard sliding up and covering UITextField/UITextView without needing you to writing any code and much more…

Comment: Thank you about the suggest.But I don't want use third part lib in the project. Now problem just scrollview enable the user touch the tableview , the tableview can't scroll.